# hot loader duplicating code (n times) instead of hot swapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

When I make a change in a component, webpack recompiles and react hot swaps the module over.. however now my code runs `n` times where `n` is the amount of times hot module swapping has taken place. For example, I make a change and now the functions are being run twice. I make another change, and the functions are being run three times. I can place a `console.log(Date.now())` in the dispatchToken on my store and I can see it being run `n` times.

Store: http://pastebin.com/PVnyf572

webpack.config.js: http://pastebin.com/MsziqH9v

and I run webpack-dev-server with `webpack-dev-server app/client.js --inline --hot --colors`

When I make a complicated change, I often get the follow error message (although this does not happen if I change line 60 of Store to increase the health by say, 10, instead of 6):

> It appears that React Hot Loader isn't configured correctly. If you're using NPM, make sure your dependencies don't drag duplicate React distributions into their node_modules and that require("react") corresponds to the React instance you render your app with. If you're using a precompiled version of React, see https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/docs#usage-with-external-react for integration instructions.

Comment: Are you sure you're not having two separate copies of React loaded on a page giving you the error message? For example, in the Developer Tools / Sources, if you Ctrl+O or Cmd+O, and type React, do you have only one React.js ? [Example](https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*uRi1xESkWG6xJQIsKNhsZA.png)

Answer (score 3):

i think your webpack configuration is not appropriate . use this boilerplate then run your code i think your problem will be solved

https://github.com/tapos007/ReactJS-MobX-Webpack-Boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're hot-reloading something that has side-effects.

Webpack documentation provides [a few examples](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) to show how to handle hot reloading.

Based on your pastebin code I would guess that this is a side-effect:

```
    this.dispatchToken = Dispatcher.register(this.onAction.bind(this))
```

I think you need to add `module.hot` detection code to the `PlayerStore` file to 'unregister' when the module is being replaced.